# cloths clip through character model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bones, weight-painting

my friend asked me to rig him a few minecraft characters and  i have come across this and i don't know how to fix it. what im trying to do is have the grey cube not clip in and out of the clothing. make it flush with the chest. it seems to lack behind when i rotate the hip bone. also, i have checked the weight of it and nothing has anymore weight on it, only the hip bone. also, the hip bone has 1.000 weight on the cube that clips in and out.

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: have you seen https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49256/cloth-colliding-through-mesh or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44287/how-can-i-make-sure-that-simulated-cloth-doesnt-go-through-other-objects ?

Comment: i have. the thing that makes it hard is the cloth piece cant use a cloth simulation. i need it to stay on the same line as the green line. would i do this with weight paint?